# What is the correct way to implement an abstract variable in a class in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop

I've seen some different ways to implement abstract methods, like:

**First Method: importing ABC**

```
from abc import ABC

class X(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def abstractmethod(self):
        pass
```

**Second method: raise NotImplementedError**

```
class X:
    def abstractmethod(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

I want to know two different things.

1) Which is the most accepted way to treat abstraction in Python?; and

2) How do I approach this for variables?

Answer (score 1):

It mostly comes down to preference, I think, but from what code I've seen, the ABC way is more accepted, as it offers an extra safety guarantee of not letting you instantiate any class that includes methods tagged as abstract with the `@abstractmethod` decorator.

For variables, you can use the `@property` decorator on top of the `@abstractmethod`, like this

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Test(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def test(self):
        pass


class TestImpl(Test):
    @property
    def test(self):
        return 1


Test()  # TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Test with abstract methods test
TestImpl().test  # 1
```